# AudioTrack$InitializationException: AudioTrack init failed: 0, Config(44100, 12, 44100)

Tags: android, mediaplayer

В приложении использую *ExoPlayer*.
Получаю следующие логи:

> 02-15 11:09:21.693 31031-31196/org.ufanet.iptv E/OMXMaster: A component of name 'OMX.qcom.audio.decoder.aac' already exists, ignoring this one.
>   02-15 11:09:21.793 31031-31225/org.ufanet.iptv E/OMXMaster: A component of name 'OMX.qcom.audio.decoder.aac' already exists, ignoring this one.
>   02-15 11:09:21.833 31031-31196/org.ufanet.iptv E/android.media.AudioTrack: getMinBufferSize(): error querying hardware
>   02-15 11:09:21.833 31031-31196/org.ufanet.iptv E/AudioTrack-JNI: Error creating AudioTrack: Could not get AudioSystem frame count.
>   02-15 11:09:21.833 31031-31196/org.ufanet.iptv E/android.media.AudioTrack: Error code -16 when initializing AudioTrack.
>   02-15 11:09:21.843 31031-31196/org.ufanet.iptv E/ExoPlayerImplInternal: Internal track renderer error.
>                                                                           com.google.android.exoplayer.ExoPlaybackException: com.google.android.exoplayer.audio.AudioTrack$InitializationException: AudioTrack init failed: 0, Config(44100, 12, 44100)
>                                                                               at com.google.android.exoplayer.MediaCodecAudioTrackRenderer.processOutputBuffer(MediaCodecAudioTrackRenderer.java:335)
>                                                                               at com.google.android.exoplayer.MediaCodecTrackRenderer.drainOutputBuffer(MediaCodecTrackRenderer.java:828)
>                                                                               at com.google.android.exoplayer.MediaCodecTrackRenderer.doSomeWork(MediaCodecTrackRenderer.java:458)
>                                                                               at com.google.android.exoplayer.ExoPlayerImplInternal.doSomeWork(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:431)
>                                                                               at com.google.android.exoplayer.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:213)
>                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>                                                                               at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
>                                                                               at com.google.android.exoplayer.util.PriorityHandlerThread.run(PriorityHandlerThread.java:40)
>                                                                            Caused by: com.google.android.exoplayer.audio.AudioTrack$InitializationException: AudioTrack init failed: 0, Config(44100, 12, 44100)
>                                                                               at com.google.android.exoplayer.audio.AudioTrack.checkAudioTrackInitialized(AudioTrack.java:799)
>                                                                               at com.google.android.exoplayer.audio.AudioTrack.initialize(AudioTrack.java:340)
>                                                                               at com.google.android.exoplayer.audio.AudioTrack.initialize(AudioTrack.java:314)
>                                                                               at com.google.android.exoplayer.MediaCodecAudioTrackRenderer.processOutputBuffer(MediaCodecAudioTrackRenderer.java:330)
>                                                                               at com.google.android.exoplayer.MediaCodecTrackRenderer.drainOutputBuffer(MediaCodecTrackRenderer.java:828) 
>                                                                               at com.google.android.exoplayer.MediaCodecTrackRenderer.doSomeWork(MediaCodecTrackRenderer.java:458) 
>                                                                               at com.google.android.exoplayer.ExoPlayerImplInternal.doSomeWork(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:431) 
>                                                                               at com.google.android.exoplayer.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:213) 
>                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
>                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
>                                                                               at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61) 
>                                                                               at com.google.android.exoplayer.util.PriorityHandlerThread.run(PriorityHandlerThread.java:40) 
>   02-15 11:09:22.113 31031-31031/org.ufanet.iptv E/EventLogger: internalError [0.71, audioTrackInitializationError]
>                                                                 com.google.android.exoplayer.audio.AudioTrack$InitializationException: AudioTrack init failed: 0, Config(44100, 12, 44100)
>                                                                     at com.google.android.exoplayer.audio.AudioTrack.checkAudioTrackInitialized(AudioTrack.java:799)
>                                                                     at com.google.android.exoplayer.audio.AudioTrack.initialize(AudioTrack.java:340)
>                                                                     at com.google.android.exoplayer.audio.AudioTrack.initialize(AudioTrack.java:314)
>                                                                     at com.google.android.exoplayer.MediaCodecAudioTrackRenderer.processOutputBuffer(MediaCodecAudioTrackRenderer.java:330)
>                                                                     at com.google.android.exoplayer.MediaCodecTrackRenderer.drainOutputBuffer(MediaCodecTrackRenderer.java:828)
>                                                                     at com.google.android.exoplayer.MediaCodecTrackRenderer.doSomeWork(MediaCodecTrackRenderer.java:458)
>                                                                     at com.google.android.exoplayer.ExoPlayerImplInternal.doSomeWork(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:431)
>                                                                     at com.google.android.exoplayer.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:213)
>                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>                                                                     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
>                                                                     at com.google.android.exoplayer.util.PriorityHandlerThread.run(PriorityHandlerThread.java:40)
>   02-15 11:09:22.113 31031-31031/org.ufanet.iptv E/EventLogger: playerFailed [0.77]
>                                                                 com.google.android.exoplayer.ExoPlaybackException: com.google.android.exoplayer.audio.AudioTrack$InitializationException: AudioTrack init failed: 0, Config(44100, 12, 44100)
>                                                                     at com.google.android.exoplayer.MediaCodecAudioTrackRenderer.processOutputBuffer(MediaCodecAudioTrackRenderer.java:335)
>                                                                     at com.google.android.exoplayer.MediaCodecTrackRenderer.drainOutputBuffer(MediaCodecTrackRenderer.java:828)
>                                                                     at com.google.android.exoplayer.MediaCodecTrackRenderer.doSomeWork(MediaCodecTrackRenderer.java:458)
>                                                                     at com.google.android.exoplayer.ExoPlayerImplInternal.doSomeWork(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:431)
>                                                                     at com.google.android.exoplayer.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:213)
>                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>                                                                     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
>                                                                     at com.google.android.exoplayer.util.PriorityHandlerThread.run(PriorityHandlerThread.java:40)
>                                                                  Caused by: com.google.android.exoplayer.audio.AudioTrack$InitializationException: AudioTrack init failed: 0, Config(44100, 12, 44100)
>                                                                     at com.google.android.exoplayer.audio.AudioTrack.checkAudioTrackInitialized(AudioTrack.java:799)
>                                                                     at com.google.android.exoplayer.audio.AudioTrack.initialize(AudioTrack.java:340)
>                                                                     at com.google.android.exoplayer.audio.AudioTrack.initialize(AudioTrack.java:314)
>                                                                     at com.google.android.exoplayer.MediaCodecAudioTrackRenderer.processOutputBuffer(MediaCodecAudioTrackRenderer.java:330)
>                                                                     at com.google.android.exoplayer.MediaCodecTrackRenderer.drainOutputBuffer(MediaCodecTrackRenderer.java:828) 
>                                                                     at com.google.android.exoplayer.MediaCodecTrackRenderer.doSomeWork(MediaCodecTrackRenderer.java:458) 
>                                                                     at com.google.android.exoplayer.ExoPlayerImplInternal.doSomeWork(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:431) 
>                                                                     at com.google.android.exoplayer.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:213) 
>                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
>                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
>                                                                     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61) 
>                                                                     at com.google.android.exoplayer.util.PriorityHandlerThread.run(PriorityHandlerThread.java:40)

Ключевым сообщением  считается:

> 02-15 11:05:40.093 29446-29446/org.ufanet.iptv D/IPTV: exception: com.google.android.exoplayer.ExoPlaybackException: com.google.android.exoplayer.audio.AudioTrack$InitializationException: AudioTrack init failed: 0, Config(44100, 12, 44100)

В гугле на эту тему внятной информации не нашел. Возникает лишь на одном устройстве(из тех что на руках) - *HighScreen Omega Pirme S*. Версия андройда 4.3(18). На устройствах ниже и выше версией проблем нету.